# MySQL multiple filter conditions which should only apply if previous filter returns no result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database table **Change** with columns **change_id**, **user_name**, **change_effective_date**. I want to retrieve the latest effective change for a user before today. And if there are no changes effective for a user before today, then the future effective changes should be retrieved. What would be the MySQL query for it?

Suppose the table is,

CHANGE_ID | USER_NAME | EFFECTIVE_DATE

```
1         BOB         2019-03-01
2         VIC         2019-04-01
3         MARK        2019-08-01
4         BOB         2019-08-01
5         VIC         2019-08-01
6         MARK        2019-09-01
```

the query should return, if today is 2019-06-01

CHANGE_ID | USER_NAME | EFFECTIVE_DATE

```
1         BOB         2019-03-01
2         VIC         2019-04-01
3         MARK        2019-08-01
```

Since Mark does not have a record previous to today , his most recent future record should be retrieved.

Note: All dates are in YYYY-MM-DD format.

Comment: provide sample data and expected output

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this? According to your logic, MARK should return 2019-09-01. Right?

```
SELECT A.USER_NAME ,
CASE 
    WHEN B.mx_date_b IS NULL THEN a.mx_date_a 
    ELSE b.mx_date_b 
END AS EFFECTIVE_DATE
FROM 
(
    SELECT USER_NAME,
    MAX(EFFECTIVE_DATE) mx_date_a
    FROM `Change`  
    GROUP BY USER_NAME
)A
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT USER_NAME,
    MAX(EFFECTIVE_DATE) mx_date_b
    FROM `Change` 
    WHERE EFFECTIVE_DATE < DATE(NOW())
    GROUP BY USER_NAME
)B 
ON A.USER_NAME = B.USER_NAME
```